# Reading URL from property file in SOAP UI

Tags: web-services, automated-tests, soapui

to test the webservice in the application i am working in, I have prepared a test suite using SOAP UI. In that i have included multiple test cases. Now in our production env there are multiple vtiers . For this I want my endpoint url configured in a property file and want soap ui to execute the test suite One by one on the endpoints given in the property. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you have multiple endpoints? Are you using soapUI Pro or OS? There are multiple ways to do this, if you can tell me what you have done I can help you refine your approach or suggest an alternate approach.

Comment: No its not pro version . I have created a sample test project and provided endpoint urls in a text file. then I declared a variable for endpoint url . this variable takes value from property file . However when i provided multiple urls it takes the last url from the list. I want my request to try all the url given in the property file.

Comment: How are you reading the text file?

Comment: I used following link for my reference :http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-properties.html

Comment: Akshu, that link doesn't say how to read data from text file. It explains how to have a centralized endpoint which is correct, I use it for my current client. What you need is a way to read each endpoint from the text/properties file, set the centralized endpoint execute all the test cases with that endpoint looping till the last endpoint in the file. Now my question to you is, do you need the code to do this? or do you want to show your code so that i can help you fix it?

Comment: I didnt wrote any code for this . I was exploring SOAPUI tool so that testing team of application i am working in could have a way to execute this scenario using a simple looking tool. From development prospective we have separate java code to execute all the test cases on webservice endpoint on all vtiers by making http call. However we cannot share the same with Testing team. So What i am looking is a way to do same with SOAP UI.